# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException not specifying missing class

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am getting the following error but the weird thing is that it is not specifying the class that is missing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3681)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000 (ActivityThread.java:229)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1903)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7406)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3676)
```

ps.: The error only occurs in production. Emulator/test devices are fine

Comment: Try to run in debug mode or to enable the log level.

Comment: I agree: the real question here is not how to *solve* this problem, but how to efficiently *debug* it, to identify the root cause. Which might or might not be a missing class.

Comment: Debug mode doesn't help. This crash occurs in production only.

Answer (score 0):

Check Proguard.txt or proguard configuration file.
Proguard might be removing some classes while shrinking/obfuscation.

If you're using any external libraries, you need to add code to keep those classes in proguard file.

Comment: I did this. What is weird is that I didn't change any library. They are all the same. No updates or whatever. This last version was a internal C++ correction only

Answer (score 0):

Clean the Project then Rebuild the project it may work.

Comment: didn't work. I cleaned the project, deleted all the build folders , rebuilt and re-published. Getting the same error